# Android: mp4 H.264 - baseband not supported

Tags: android, mp4

Android < 3.0 does not support video playback for mp4 with H.264 baseband.

However, it also does not push an error message because it can play the sound (without video).
I'd like to add a proper error/exception handler. How to get a notice in case of an issue that disables video playback?

Comment: does nobody have an idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to check for the android version.

If the version is earlier than 3.0, throw exception.

Comment: So it's really up to me to check any in/compatibilities instead of catching an error event or notice telling me about missing codecs or features?

Comment: It didn't say it's the only way, but it is an alternative to the solution you're seeking.

Comment: lets keep this way as fallback solution. i still have hope that someone here knows about an alternative. debugging on my own did not bring any notice for handling this issue in a proper way :-(